# Increasing div's width doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I would like to achieve is when scrolling to the end of row(right arrow) then to have selection div stop on the last element. Before I was adding few dummy cells and it worked. But now I decided to just increase width of row div by some amount.

```
if(!rows[currentRowIndex].reachedEnd)
{
    console.log("increasing ");
    $("#row" + currentRowIndex).width("+=210");
    rows[currentRowIndex].reachedEnd = true;
}
```

This doesn't work for some reason. I even tried to increase by some bigger number but it jumps to some unexpected location, which means I don't understand well what is going on with div after width is changed.

Working copy(resize window to show 2 cells in the client area) https://jsfiddle.net/souren/98rddfzp/3/

UPD1:

I even tried:

```
$("#row" + currentRowIndex).width($("#row" + currentRowIndex).width() + 210);
```

with same result.

Comment: I have printer the width of the .row before I change width and it shows only as much as my window resized. But I was expecting to get the whole width of div, where I added so many cells and it's not currently visible. Can somebody explain me why .row width only gives visible part?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) takes the actual width as parameter and does not evaluate expressions. You have to do so yourself.

Here's an working example:

```js
$(function () {
  var $div = $('#myDiv')
  $('#increase').on('click', function () {
    $div.width($div.width() + 250)
  })
})
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button id="increase">Increase</div>
```

Comment: `$div.width(function(_, value) { return value + 250; })`

Comment: I thought so, but tested just now and see that `width("+=210");` is working.

Comment: There might be some other problem, since the way you suggested didn't help. https://jsfiddle.net/souren/98rddfzp/4/

Comment: Basically the more I add width, the less I can scroll to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this example, this will solve your problem::

**HTML**

```
<div class="testDiv" style="background-color: grey; width: 100px;">Rana</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        $(".testDiv").width($(".testDiv").width() + 210);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I am not able to reach to last cell by scrolling. https://jsfiddle.net/souren/98rddfzp/4/